# The matrix has invalid characters

Tags: javascript, canvas

I just saw [**this matrix on HN in less than 600 bytes**](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5388444)

Here's the full source:

```
<body style=margin:0 onload="for(s=window.screen,w=q.width=s.width,
    h=q.height=s.height,m=Math.random,p=[],i=0;i<256;p[i++]=1);
    setInterval('9Style=\'rgba(0,0,0,.05)\'9Rect(0,0,w,h)9Style=\'#0F0\';
    p.map(function(v,i){9Text(String.fromCharCode(3e4+m()*33),i*10,v);
    p[i]=v>758+m()*1e4?0:v+10})'.split(9).join(';q.getContext(\'2d\').fill'),33)">
    <canvas id=q>
```

My question is how does an assignment for a variable start with a number: `setInterval('9Style=\'rgba(0,0,0,.05...)` I thought js variables can't start with a number.
Shouldn't this be an invalid lhs (left hand side) assignment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right, identifiers cannot start with a number. If you look closer, the `9` is replaced by `;q.getContext('2d').fill`.

The loop decomposed in setting variables and creating an array `p` containing 256 `1`s:

```
s = window.screen,
w = q.width = s.width,
h = q.height = s.height,
m = Math.random,
p = [];
for (i = 0; i < 256; p[i++] = 1);
```

Remainder:

```
setInterval(
    '9Style=\'rgba(0,0,0,.05)\'9Rect(0,0,w,h)9Style=\'#0F0\';p.map(function(v,i){9Text(String.fromCharCode(3e4+m()*33),i*10,v);p[i]=v>758+m()*1e4?0:v+10})'
    .split(9).join(';q.getContext(\'2d\').fill')
, 33)
```

This becomes:

```
setInterval(";q.getContext('2d').fillStyle='rgba(0,0,0,.05)';q.getContext('2d').fillRect(0,0,w,h);q.getContext('2d').fillStyle='#0F0';p.map(function(v,i){;q.getContext('2d').fillText(String.fromCharCode(3e4+m()*33),i*10,v);p[i]=v>758+m()*1e4?0:v+10})", 33);
```

Putting this code in http://jsbeautifier.org/ gives:

```
;
q.getContext('2d').fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,.05)';
q.getContext('2d').fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
q.getContext('2d').fillStyle = '#0F0';
p.map(function (v, i) {;
    q.getContext('2d').fillText(String.fromCharCode(3e4 + m() * 33), i * 10, v);
    p[i] = v > 758 + m() * 1e4 ? 0 : v + 10
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not start with a number. It's only a string, that is split:

`'9Style ....'.split(9).join(...`